# How to use pom.xml property in junit test class

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, junit4

I have declare a property in pom.xml

```
<PROPERTY_KEY>d:/../.../abc.properties</PROPERTY_KEY>
```

and then used

```
<plugin>
    <configuration>
        <replacements>
            <replacement>
                <token>APP_PROPERTY</token>
                <value>${PROPERTY_KEY}</value>
                ....
</plugin>
```

and have used APP_PROPERTY in my dispatcher-servlet.xml and in controller classes as well. It's working fine as in this case control comes through web.xml and this web.xml has an entry for my dispatcher-servlet.xml.
But when I want to use this same APP_PROPERTY in my JUNI test class, it is not getting resolved. 
I have to create a new dispatcher-servlet-test.xml file (and put it under /src/main/resources folder) as my actual dispatcher-servlet.xml is not working from JUnit test class. Now my JUnit test class is able to pick dispatcher-servlet-test.xml. But, it is not able to resolve properties (APP_PROPERTY) that I have defined in my pom.xml.
I'm using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class in my test class.
What should I do to get these property resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Resources for tests need to live under **src/test/resources**, you should move your dispatcher-servlet-test.xml there. Once moved, it's likely not being filtered as a resource, the stanza you want is something like:

```
<build>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
      <include>**/dispatcher-servlet-test.xml</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
```

You may already have a similar stanza in your POM, or if you're working on a larger project the parent pom.xml may have a stanza declaring:

```
<filtering>true</filtering>
```

Comment: Hi, for some reason its not working for me. I tried your suggestion.    My dispatcher-servlet-test.xml contains these lines:        <br>    <util:properties id="applicationProperties" location="file:${APP_PROPERTY}/application.properties" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="file:${APP_PROPERTY}/application.properties" /> ,<br>  My pom.xml has an entry as suggested by you.